# Parsing PCAP file into XML file using Perl

Tags: php, xml, perl, libpcap

I'm trying to get Perl to read an offline pcap file and save the output into XML file so I can work with it in PHP.

I can't use PHP because its not my server but I can Perl. So my aim is to convert the PCAP file into XML so I have fun with it.

I have no idea where to start and have looked at the Perl Net::Pcap but I just don't understand the language.

Any ideas on what I should do?
Thank-you
Paul

Comment: http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2010/03/parsing-pcap-files-with-perl.html

Comment: I know this is super old and you may not have this option but python with scapy would be perfect for what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Using Net::Pcap is a decent idea, although figuring out the format you'd want to write out the capture in doesn't seem all that easy.  My favourite solution would be to use tshark (the command line version of wireshark) like so:

```
tshark -r $dmp_filename -Tpsml
```

This would give you the output in a XML [standard format](http://www.nbee.org/doku.php?id=netpdl%3apsml_specification).

Of course if you don't have tshark, not very helpful...